# Add custom url for my web service in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress and i am creating an extension for wordpress.  I searched a-lot but didn't find any solution. May be my question is duplicate but i didn't find any solution.  My issue is :

I want to create a  custom url for my extension api. Like
some will post data on that url and i will save data in database. My url should be `www.example.com/custom_url`

There will be no page and no template for my url, it's a kind of web service.

So in my extension i want that when any user install that extension this custom_url will automatically active for them.

I tried `add_rewrite_rule` , `add_rewrite_endpoints`  etc. But no success.

please suggest me or provide me any link where it is described.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the tutorial on WordPress forum:

> **What are endpoints?**
>
> Using endpoints allows you to easily create rewrite rules to catch the
>   normal WordPress URLs, but with a little extra at the end. For
>   example, you could use an endpoint to match all post URLs followed by
>   “gallery” and display all of the images used in a post, e.g.
>   http://example.com/my-fantastic-post/gallery/.

Full Tutorial here: https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/

So it is not helpful for creating virtual pages as you need.

However, As per the Following post on WordPress Stack Exchange, it is possible to create virtual pages using `add_rewrite_rule`

[How do you create a “virtual” page in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress)

Here is some excerpt from original article:

> first we add a rewrite rule that adds a query vars, then we make this
>   query var public, and then we need to check for the existence of this
>   query var to pass the control to our plugin file. By the time we do
>   this, the usual WordPress initialization will have happened (we break
>   away right before the regular post query).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_internal' );
function wpse9870_init_internal()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'my-api.php$', 'index.php?wpse9870_api=1', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse9870_api';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wpse9870_api', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        include 'my-api.php';
        exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

[Codex Page `add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Answer (score 3):

1). create action for virtual page.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'apicall' );


function apicall() {

$callapi = $_GET['API'];

if($callapi=='YOUR API Name'){

            header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

{{YOUR LOGIC}}

        exit;
}   
}
```

Write on browser
URL: www.YOURDOMAIN.com/?API=YOUR API NAME